# What is causing my ToDataSourceResult error in my KendoUI Core Application?

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, repository-pattern

I have created a .NET Core application with WebAPI and KendoUI.  I've added a generic repository, when I try to add a datasource to my Kendo Grid I am getting an error on the `.ToDataSourceResult()` message of:

> < Task< IEnumerable< Vessel>> does not contain a definition for
>   'ToDataSourceResult' and the best extension method overload
>   'QueryableExtensions.ToDataSourceResult(DataTable, DataSourceRequest)'
>   requires a receiver of type 'DataTable'

I followed the Kendo documentation for Core and WebApi to complete this method but I can't get it to work.  I've attached the code from my project related to this error and data.

**Controllers/HomeController**

```
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Senua.Interfaces;
using Senua.Models;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Senua.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IVesselRepository service;

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public DataSourceResult GetVessels([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return service.GetAllVesselsAsync().ToDataSourceResult(request); <----Error appears here.
        }
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }

    }
}
```

**Views/Home/Index**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Senua.Models.Vessel>()
    .Name("vessel_grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource =>
        dataSource
            .WebApi()
            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.Id);
            })
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetVessels", "Home"))
          ))

<script>
    function error_handler(e) {
        var errors = $.parseJSON(e.xhr.responseText);
        if (errors) {
            alert("Errors:\n" + errors.join("\n"));
        }
    }
</script>
```

**DAL/VesselRepository**

```
using Senua.Interfaces;
using Senua.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Senua.DAL
{
    public class VesselRepository : Repository<Vessel>, IVesselRepository
    {
        public VesselRepository(LocalContext repositoryContext)
            : base(repositoryContext)
        {
        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Vessel>> GetAllVesselsAsync()
        {
            var vessel = await FindAllAsync();
            return vessel.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
        }
}
```

**Interfaces/IVesselRepository**

```
using Senua.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Senua.Interfaces
{
    public interface IVesselRepository
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<Vessel>> GetAllVesselsAsync();
        Task<Vessel> GetVesselByIdAsync(int Id);
        Task CreateVesselAsync(Vessel vessel);
        Task UpdateVesselAsync(Vessel vessel);
        Task DeleteVesselAsync(Vessel vessel);
    }
}
```

**DAL/Repository**

```
using Senua.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Senua.DAL
{
    public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        protected LocalContext DbContext { get; set; }
        public Repository(LocalContext _context)
        {
            this.DbContext = _context;
        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindAllAsync()
        {
            return await this.DbContext.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
        }        
    }
}
```

**Interfaces/IRepository**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Senua.Interfaces
{
    public interface IRepository<T>
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindAllAsync();
        Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindByConditionAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
        void Create(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        Task SaveAsync();
    }
}
```

I need some guidance on this one, I've never set up an async repos before so it's a little new however, from what I can see, it's ok and I've tested with postman.  I noticed that there is also a 'ToDataSourceAsync' but, after trying that as well it didn't work either.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ToDataSourceResult`, it is the method for `IEnumerable`.

For `GetAllVesselsAsync()`, it returns a task.

Try code below

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<DataSourceResult> GetVessels([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var result = await service.GetAllVesselsAsync();
    return result.ToDataSourceResult(request); 
}
```

Update

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IVesselRepository service;
    public HomeController(IVesselRepository service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, the solution partially worked.  Once I put this code in I get a warning that `private IVesselRepository service;` is never assigned too and therefore will always have the value of null.  I'm not sure why this is as it's assigned in the method `var result = await service.GetAllVesselsAsync();`.  Do you have any thoughts on this or is this a new issue?

Comment: @Yanayaya You should inject `IVesselRepository` to `HomeController` constructor.

Comment: Of course, thanks.  I have now done that and I can see the data being returned to the method.  Annoyingly the grid is not populating but the data is being returned >:(

Comment: @Yanayaya I would suggest to start a new issue.

Comment: The grid not returning results was because of the missing `JsonOptions` line: `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my Kendo MVC Grid that needed async functionality.
It's a complex case where you need to use an asynchronous DataSourceResult to bind grid data from an api:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private HttpClient _client = ApiHelper.Client;
    private Uri baseUri = ApiHelper._Client.BaseAddress;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    DataSourceResult result;
    JsonResult final;
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetList([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        const int limit = 100;
        List<myModel> myModelList = new List<myModel>();
        using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, baseUri + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["V3BaseUri"] + "resource?offset=" + offset + "&limit=" + limit))
        using (var response = await ApiHelper.Client.SendAsync(req))
        {
             response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                try
                {
                    var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    myModelList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myModel>>(content);
                    result = await myModelList.ToDataSourceResultAsync(request);
                    final = Json(result);
                    return final;
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    string message = exc.Message;
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception message: {0}", message);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

And in my view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Project.Models.myModel>()
            .Name("grid")
            .AutoBind(true)
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(c => c.Id)
                  .Width(80).Title("Entity Id");
                columns.Bound(c => c.NameOfInstitution);
                columns.Bound(c => c.Addresses).ClientTemplate("#=generateAddress(Addresses)#").Title("Address");
                columns.Bound(c => c.InstitutionTelephones).ClientTemplate("#=generatePhone(InstitutionTelephones)#").Title("Phone");

            })
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 750px;" })
            .Scrollable()
            .Groupable()
            .Sortable()
            .Pageable()
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(99)
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetList", "Home"))
            ).NoRecords(x => x.Template("<div class='empty-grid'>NO RECORDS</div>")))
```